# Bash locale sensitive globbing on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, locale

Scenario on both Linux(CentOS) and OS X(Yosemite):

```
$ touch A B C X Y Z a b c x y z

$ locale
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

On OS X I am using a case-sensitive filesystem.

Bash 4.1.2 on Linux:

```
$ echo [A-Z]
A b B c C x X y Y z Z
```

This is the expected output, the `LC_COLLATE` for this locale is followed.

Bash 4.3.39 on OS X:

```
$ echo [A-Z]
A B C X Y Z
```

This appears to be the same as locale ANSI, C, or POSIX.  So, it looks like on OS X the locale is ignored by globbing.

Why is it inconsistent?  Is there any way to get the locale sensitive result on OS X?

**Edit**:
OS X:  `LC_ALL` is explicitly set in `.bash_profile` using:

```
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

locale on OS X:

```
bash-4.3$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

locale on Linux:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8
```

**Edit**

Format of the filesystem is Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled).

@chepner suggested that I didn't have separate files on OS X.  Two things here, the inodes are different, and the glob construct `?` gave all the files in upper and lower case:

```
bash-4.3$ ls -li ?
559 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 A
560 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 B
561 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 C
562 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 X
563 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 Y
564 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 Z
565 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 a
566 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 b
567 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 c
568 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 x
569 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 y
570 -rw-r--r--  1 clivedarke  staff  0 Aug  4 17:23 z
```

Also:

```
bash-4.3$ echo 'lower' > a
bash-4.3$ echo 'upper' > A
bash-4.3$ cat a
lower
bash-4.3$ cat A
upper

bash-4.3$ diff a A
1c1
< lower
---
> upper
```

Comment: could you please paste the full output of the `locale` command on both shells?

Comment: @WalterTross: done, sorry for the delay, I had to copy using a USB stick!

Comment: Are you *sure* you have a case-sensitive file system? With the default HFS+ file system, I have a file `file.txt`; `ls -i file.txt File.txt` confirms that the case of the initial doesn't matter and that both refer to the same inode. However, `ls F*` says there are no matches. I think your touch command created 5 uppercase files, then simply touched those 5 again with the lowercase names.

Comment: @chepner:  a reasonable suggestion (as always) but `ls -i` seems to confirm that they have different inodes.

Comment: @chepner: I added a few more details to the post to confirm they are separate files.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how all this works; on a Linux machine here, `echo [A-Z]` only shows `A`, but `echo [a-z]` shows both `a` and `A` (in a shell started with `LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 bash`). Both `zsh` and `dash` stay completely case-sensitive with the same locale.

Comment: @chepner:  Bash has been locale sensitive for a very long time but it is the only shell I know of that is like that.  Korn shell (88 & 93) has always used character set order, which is what most people expect anyway.  I can't explain your Linux results, but I regularly see my results on many different distros of Linux, as well as UNIX.  The surprise was that I didn't get that on OS X.  It looks like I'll have to dive into the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Digging int the source code I found in `bash-4.3/lib/glob/smatch.c` the following comment:

```
/* We use strcoll(3) for range comparisons in bracket expressions,
   even though it can have unwanted side effects in locales
   other than POSIX or US.  For instance, in the de locale, [A-Z] matches
   all characters.  If GLOB_ASCIIRANGE is non-zero, and we're not forcing
   the use of strcoll (e.g., for explicit collating symbols), we use
   straight ordering as if in the C locale. */
```

In `configure` I found:

```
--enable-glob-asciiranges-default
                      force bracket range expressions in pattern matching
                      to use the C locale by default
```

So I guess that was set when compiled.  Need more digging.